# Creating subclass of QLabel through Qt Creator C++ Wizard?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

*Alas, this is an embarrassingly stupid question:*

**Environment: Qt 5.1 Qt Creator 2.8  OSX 1.7.5;**

How do I create a subclass of QLabel through the Qt Creator C++ Wizard?

Specifically, what is the `base class` and `type information`? I have tried it about three different ways and end up with various compile errors (below). Qt has been working fine so doesn't seem like an install issue so it must be a...user issue.

**Answer: The base class is just `QLabel` and the type information is `QWidget`
Apparently I had some other issue going on which was causing the compile errors.**

---

If I set the type information to `QWidget` or `None` I get the error

> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

If I set the type information to `QObject` I get the error:

> invalid conversion from 'QObject*' to 'QWidget*'

**UPDATE**

```
01:25:29: Running steps for project LabelImageTest...
01:25:29: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
01:25:29: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -o mainwindow.o /Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest/mainwindow.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -o customlabel.o /Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest/customlabel.cpp
/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/bin/rcc -name images /Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest/images.qrc -o qrc_images.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -o qrc_images.o qrc_images.cpp
/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/bin/moc -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D__APPLE__ -D__GNUC__=4 -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib /Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest/mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/bin/moc -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D__APPLE__ -D__GNUC__=4 -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib /Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest/customlabel.h -o moc_customlabel.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I/Users/rise/QT_workspace/LabelImageTest -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/rise/Qt/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -o moc_customlabel.o moc_customlabel.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o LabelImageTest.app/Contents/MacOS/LabelImageTest main.o mainwindow.o customlabel.o qrc_images.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_customlabel.o   -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -framework QtWidgets -F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/rise/Qt//5.1.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MainWindow::on_label_linkActivated(QString const&)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)in moc_mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [LabelImageTest.app/Contents/MacOS/LabelImageTest] Error 1
01:25:34: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project LabelImageTest (kit: QT 5.1)
When executing step 'Make'
01:25:34: Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you can do it from Qt Wizard,

But if you prefer code than following how it's done,

```
//in header file
#include <QLabel>
class MyLabel: public QLabel{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyLabel( QWidget* parent=0);
   //other methods
};

//in cpp file
MyLabel::MyLabel( QWidget* parent) 
    : QLabel(parent)
{
}
```

You can create its instance by following code

```
MyLabel* label = new MyLabel();
//layout->addWidget(label);
```

Comment: Thanks - yeah, that's about what I had. Just tried it with your code and still get the error "error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" I guess something else is going on.

Comment: can you paste complete error in your question?, whole compile output. This issue seems installation issue.

Comment: Just updated my question with the compile output. I installed Qt 5.1 using the online installer for OSX here: http://qt-project.org/downloads - Ok new update: just started a new session with new project and made a custom QLabel through the C++ Wizard and it worked. I had been screwing around promoting/demoting QLabels in the prior file so maybe I screwed something up in that. I'll mark this as accepted/ thanks for your help.